# Set values in input type date and time in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have two input fields:

```html
<input type="date" id="currentDate">
<input type="time" id="currentTime">
```

How can I set these fields to the current date/time?

Comment: With which code are you having trouble? Please edit your question to show what you've tried and what specifically goes wrong.

Answer (score 55):

You can just set the `value` of the input field with the respective formats:

- `date` is `yyyy-MM-dd`
- `time` is `HH:mm`

Using your example, you can do something simple like:

```
var date = new Date();
var currentDate = date.toISOString().substring(0,10);
var currentTime = date.toISOString().substring(11,16);

document.getElementById('currentDate').value = currentDate;
document.getElementById('currentTime').value = currentTime;
```

Comment: Your code doesn't work if `getHours()` or `getMinutes()` returns values under `10`. The time input will reject strings like `"4:8"`. You need to ensure that each component (hours and minutes) has a leading zero, e.g. `"04:08"`

Comment: What does "   .slice(0,10)   " does? Does it take the first 10 digits and set them for the appropriate date format ? Do you have any helpful links ?

Comment: `.toISOString()` only might cause a bug issue, because default it will calculate UTC conversion, to prevent it automate calculate, you should call with `toISOString(true)` to achieve it.

Comment: @NattaWang `toISOString()` accepts no arguments: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toISOString#Syntax

Comment: toISOString() didn't work for me but toString() did

Answer (score 20):

```
var date = new Date();

var day = date.getDate(),
    month = date.getMonth() + 1,
    year = date.getFullYear(),
    hour = date.getHours(),
    min  = date.getMinutes();

month = (month < 10 ? "0" : "") + month;
day = (day < 10 ? "0" : "") + day;
hour = (hour < 10 ? "0" : "") + hour;
min = (min < 10 ? "0" : "") + min;

var today = year + "-" + month + "-" + day,
    displayTime = hour + ":" + min; 

document.getElementById('formdate').value = today;      
document.getElementById("formtime").value = displayTime;
```

Comment: works better than the accepted answer (fixes the issue with minutes < 10)

Comment: This is the best solution on this page. Other solutions just discard the user's timezone information.

Comment: type issue galore

Answer (score 10):

On modern browsers, this is very simple:

just use HTML_element **.valueAsDate** instead of HTML_element **.value**

```js
const 
  myForm = document.querySelector('#my-form')
, dtStr  = document.querySelector('#date-time-Str')  
, localDt_now =_=>
    {
    let now = new Date()
    now.setMinutes(now.getMinutes() - now.getTimezoneOffset())
    now.setSeconds(0)       // remove seconds
    now.setMilliseconds(0) // remove milliseconds
    return now
    }

/* ------------------------------------------- *\
*      set date & time  !                       *
\* ------------------------------------------- */

myForm.inDate.valueAsDate = localDt_now()   // current date
myForm.inTime.valueAsDate = localDt_now()   // current time

/*----------------------------------- Bonus -*\
*     some Intl methods to use...             *
\*-------------------------------------------*/
const
  fxD = // dates Formats
    { ymd : Intl.DateTimeFormat( 0, { year: 'numeric', month: '2-digit', day: '2-digit' })
    , hm  : Intl.DateTimeFormat( 0, { hour12: false, hour: '2-digit', minute: '2-digit' })
    }
, fxD_parts = (d,fx) => fx.formatToParts(d).reduce((o,{type,value})=>(o[type]=value,o),{})
  ;

/*------------------------------------ Bonus -*\
*  reverse action = get date & time values !   *
\*--------------------------------------------*/
// add TZ offset to get locale values
const getLocalDt = dt => dt.setMinutes(dt.getMinutes() + dt.getTimezoneOffset())


/*----------------------------------- Bonus -*\
*  demo...                                    *
\*-------------------------------------------*/
myForm.onsubmit = e =>
  {
  e.preventDefault()

  let
    dt_D = fxD_parts( getLocalDt( myForm.inDate.valueAsDate), fxD.ymd )
  , dt_T = fxD_parts( getLocalDt( myForm.inTime.valueAsDate), fxD.hm )
    ;
  dtStr.innerHTML = ` date = ${dt_D.year} - ${dt_D.month} - ${dt_D.day} <br>`
                  + ` time = ${dt_T.hour} : ${dt_T.minute}` 
  }
```

```css
form {
  padding       : 1em 2em;
  }
label {
  display       : inline-block;
  line-height   : 1.3em;
  margin        : 1em .6em;
  font-size     : .8em;
  }
input {
  display       : block;
  margin-bottom : .6em;
  }
```

```html
<form id="my-form" method="post" action="#">
  <label>
    Date:
    <input name="inDate" type="date">
  </label>
  <label>
    Time: 
    <input name="inTime" type="time">
  </label>
  <br><br>
  <button type="submit">get Date & time (Bonus)</button>
</form>

<p id="date-time-Str">d=??? t=???</p>
```

> (previous version)
>
> ```js
> // just my preference to access form elements by names
> const myForm = document.querySelector('#my-Form')
>
> // 1: get local date and time values
> let sysDate  = new Date()  
>   , userDate = new Date(Date.UTC(sysDate.getFullYear(), sysDate.getMonth(), sysDate.getDate(),  sysDate.getHours(), sysDate.getMinutes(), 0));
>
> // 2: set interface values !
> myForm.currentDate.valueAsDate = userDate
> myForm.currentTime.valueAsDate = userDate
> ```
>
> ```html
> <form action="xxx" id="my-Form">
>
>   <input type="date" name="currentDate">
>   <br><br>
>   <input type="time" name="currentTime">
>
> </form>
> ```

Comment: great answer, although I have found that `valueAsDate` will use the UTC time of the date. I haven't found a clean solution yet

Comment: yes, internally. But when it comes to displaying the time, it is most often the case that you want to show it in the client zone. See this quick example: https://jsfiddle.net/jtmLv0dc/

Comment: I can no longer edit my comment, but what it was intended to say is `valueAsDate` will *display* the UTC time of the date

Comment: @Felipe I have updated my answer with a simplest method to set inputs to locale date/ time values

Answer (score 4):

I find that using ISOString, the format is, of course, standardised. You can simply split the string at 'T' for an array of date and time (Zulu included, you may wish to splice out the last char, 'Z').

Thus, the simplest solution I found was merely to:

```js
let tmp = new Date(Date.now());

// tmp now like: "2018-08-21T11:54:50.580Z"

let dateInputFormatted = tmp.toISOString().split('T')[0];

// 0, as split produces: ["2018-08-21", "11:54:50.580Z"]

console.log(dateInputFormatted);
```

Comment: This is not an ideal solution as it disregards the timezone information. For example: `new Date('2019-08-17T01:42:30.809680+05:30')` is in user's local timezone. If you use `.getDate()`, you'll get user's local date -- `17`. But on doing `.toISOString().split('T')`, you get the UTC date -- `16`, which is one day behind.

Answer (score 3):

> How can I set these fields to the current date/time?

If you want the date/time of the browser/client in *local time* (not in UTC/GMT!) then use

```
var date = new Date();
document.getElementById('currentDate').valueAsDate = date;
document.getElementById('currentTime').value = date.toTimeString().substring(0,5);
```

If you want more time granularity (e.g. also seconds) then enhance the "5" in the substring (e.g. to "8"). Modern browsers provide date/time pickers, enlarge the time entry field from the value provided and also respect the browsers "language/date-time format" preferences. Above solution sets date and time (hours and minutes) correctly for any browsers "language/date-time format" preferences.

Problems with other solutions are:

1. `Date.toISOString()` provides UTC/Zulu time
2. `toLocaleTimeString` might provide "9:12" instead of the required "09:12":
3. `date.toLocaleTimeString('it-IT', { hour: '2-digit', minute: '2-digit' })` works but `date.toTimeString().substring(0,5)` is shorter and without the need to pick any Locale such as 'it-IT'

Answer (score 2):

In order to convert a date to an ISO date without the time, you need to use the `getDate`, `getMonth`, etc. methods instead of getting the `ISOString` directly and manipulating the string. The latter will not take the timezone into consideration which will lead to unexpected results.

Here is a solution for the same using ES6.

```js
// Function which returns a minimum of two digits in case the value is less than 10
const getTwoDigits = (value) => value < 10 ? `0${value}` : value;

const formatDate = (date) => {
  const day = getTwoDigits(date.getDate());
  const month = getTwoDigits(date.getMonth() + 1); // add 1 since getMonth returns 0-11 for the months
  const year = date.getFullYear();

  return `${year}-${month}-${day}`;
}

const formatTime = (date) => {
  const hours = getTwoDigits(date.getHours());
  const mins = getTwoDigits(date.getMinutes());

  return `${hours}:${mins}`;
}

const date = new Date();
document.getElementById('currentDate').value = formatDate(date);
document.getElementById('currentTime').value = formatTime(date);
```

```html
<input type="date" id="currentDate">
<input type="time" id="currentTime">
```

This will now return the current date and time as per the current timezone.

Answer (score 1):

You can make two prototypes in order to reuse them:

```
    Date.prototype.dateToInput = function(){
        return this.getFullYear() + '-' + ('0' + (this.getMonth() + 1)).substr(-2,2) + '-' + ('0' + this.getDate()).substr(-2,2);
    }
    Date.prototype.timeToInput = function(){
        return  ('0' + (this.getHours())).substr(-2,2) + ':' + ('0' + this.getMinutes()).substr(-2,2);
    }
```

Then use them like this:

```
    var date = new Date();
    document.getElementById('currentDate').value = date.dateToInput();
    document.getElementById('currentTime').value = date.timeToInput();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var date = new Date();
var dateOptions = { day: '2-digit', month: '2-digit', year: 'numeric' };
var currentDate = date.toLocaleDateString('ja-JP', dateOptions).replace(/\//gi, '-');
var timeOptions = { hour: '2-digit', minute: '2-digit' };
var currentTime = date.toLocaleTimeString('it-IT', timeOptions);

document.getElementById('currentDate').value = currentDate;
document.getElementById('currentTime').value = currentTime;
```

Answer (score 0):

Suppose, you have a date (text) value in any text format.

```
Eg. myDate = 28-08-2020;
```

Now, to set it on `<input type="date"/>` you need to bring the date in "YYYY-MM-DD" format.

So,

```
var tempD = date.split("-");
myDate = tempD[2] + "-" + tempD[1] + "-" + tempD[0]; //myDate will be = 2020-08-28
document.getElementById("myDate").value = myDate ;
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use this code

`<input type="date" id="currentDate">`

and in your script , write this code

```
var date = new Date();

var day = date.getDate();
var month = date.getMonth() + 1;
var year = date.getFullYear();

if (month < 10) month = "0" + month;
if (day < 10) day = "0" + day;

var today = year + "-" + month + "-" + day +"T00:00";       
document.getElementById("currentDate").value = today;
```

Answer (score 0):

its as simple as calling the function as below:

```js
var time = new Date()
  .toLocaleTimeString("en-US", {
      hour12: false
  });

console.log("time", time);
```