# Input type date dont show value

Tags: html, angular

I have a form control that gets a date but the input doesn't show the value

```
<input formControlName="startDate" name="startDate" type="date" class="form-control">
```

I determine the value through a patchValue I tried to use `[value]` but doesn't work
I tried to convert to `new Date()` and it didn't work

```
this.form.patchValue({

  startDate: data.start,

});
```

Comment: What does "but tbm doesn't work" mean?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Set values in input type date and time in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28729634/set-values-in-input-type-date-and-time-in-javascript)

Comment: What is the value of `data.start`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Input type `date` accepts dates of the format `yyyy-mm-dd`. This means you will need to convert your dates to that format. You can convert it to an ISO date string first and then extract the date part of it but this, however, will not consider the timezone. So instead we will create a function that gets a date in the desired format while taking timezones into consideration. We can use `getDate` and `getMonth` as they consider the timezone.

```js
formatDate(date: Date | string): string {
    date = new Date(date);
    const day = `${date.getDate() < 10 ? '0' : ''}${date.getDate()}`;
    const month = `${date.getMonth() + 1 < 10 ? '0' : ''}${date.getMonth() + 1}`;
    const year = date.getFullYear();
    return `${year}-${month}-${day}`;
}
```

Then just call this function to convert the format.

```js
this.form.patchValue({
    startDate: this.formatDate(data.start)
});
```

You can also do this when you create the form. Note that even when you select a date from the input, it will bind in the same format `yyyy-mm-dd`.

Comment: Hi, I updated my answer. Previously I had not added a `1` to the month. You need to do this since month returns a value from `0-11` for the months.