# How to set hour of time element dynamically?

Tags: javascript, jquery, date, input

I have a form with input `time` type. I want to set the actual hour automatically.
This Javascript works but set a fixed hour to 08:15 :

```
<script>
     $("#myelement").val( "08:15" );
</script>
```

This script should get the actual hour but set an empty value to the field :

```
<script>
var dt = new Date();
var time = dt.getHours() + ":" + dt.getMinutes();
  $("#myelement").val( time );
</script>
```

How to fix it ?

Comment: Can you give more information about the desired behavior compared to what the script is actually doing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not displaying the time cause it's not following the 'time' format. When the time is less than 10, numbers should have a leading 0. E.g. 09:17

```
var date = new Date();

var hour = date.getHours();
var min  = date.getMinutes();
hour = (hour < 10 ? "0" : "") + hour;
min = (min < 10 ? "0" : "") + min;
var time = hour + ":" + min; 

$("#myelement").val( time );
```

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41480350/6099890

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this :

```
<script>
var d = new Date();
document.getElementById("myelement").innerHTML = d.toTimeString();
</script>
```

If you wish to stick with JQuery

```
<script>
    var d = new Date($.now());
    alert(d.getDate()+"-"+(d.getMonth() + 1)+"-"+d.getFullYear()+" "+d.getHours()+":"+d.getMinutes()+":"+d.getSeconds());
    </script>
```

See how it works :

https://jsfiddle.net/g35uxqtp/171/

Answer (score 0):

The `time` input [value](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/time#Value) needs a 24-hour format. So zero-padding the values works

```js
const dt = new Date();

// create a zero padded time value
const time = [`${dt.getHours()}`.padStart(2, "0"), 
  `${dt.getMinutes()}`.padStart(2, "0")].join(":");
const inp = document.querySelector("#myelement");

// demo
setTimeout(() => inp.value = "8:15", 1000);  // does not work
setTimeout(() => inp.value = "08:15", 2000); // works
setTimeout(() => inp.value = time, 4000);    // works
```

```html
<input type="time" id="myelement">
```