# Change date when status is updated

Tags: javascript

Hi guys I'm looking to write a javascript to change the date in the date box when I update the status select box.

For example the initial date on the datebox is 6/1/2021. And I will click on status rejected. The date should automatically change to today 6/3/21 without manually clicking the date picker box

````
<html>
<body>

<select>
    <option value="Offered">Offered</option>
    <option value="Accepted">Accepted</option>
    <option value="Rejected">Rejected</option>
</select">

  <input type="date" id="date" name="date">
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">```


</body>
</html>
````

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Set values in input type date and time in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28729634/set-values-in-input-type-date-and-time-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope this answers your question. I have added comments for better clarity. In case you have any issues, let me know.

```js
//Getting the select HTML node.
const select = document.querySelector("#select");

//Getting the date input node.
const date = document.querySelector("#date");

//Adding a change event listener to the select node.
select.addEventListener('change', () => {
        //Had to use ISOString with slice method, since the date picker only accepts the date value in "yyyy-MM-dd" format.
        date.value = new Date().toISOString().slice(0, 10);
});
```

```html
<html>
<body>

<select id="select">
    <option value="Offered">Offered</option>
    <option value="Accepted">Accepted</option>
    <option value="Rejected">Rejected</option>
</select>

  <input type="date" id="date" name="date">
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Then you have to call the onChange() event on select and remove the if condition-

```
<html>
<head>
    <script>
        function myFunction() {
            let date = new Date();

            let year = date.getFullYear();
            let month = (date.getMonth() + 1).toString().length == 1 ? '0' + (date.getMonth() + 1).toString() : (date.getMonth() + 1).toString();
            let day = date.getDay().toString().length == 1 ? '0' + date.getDay().toString() : date.getDay().toString();
            let showDate = year + '-' + month + '-' + day;
            document.getElementById("date").value = showDate;
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>

    <select id="mySelect" onchange="myFunction();">
        <option value="Offered">Tesla</option>
        <option value="Accepted">Volvo</option>
        <option value="Rejected">Mercedes</option>
    </select>

    <input type="date" id="date" name="date">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: OP says "when I update the status select box" — I think "rejected" is just an example; the date should be updated if the selection is _changed_, regardless of what the new choice is. Also, it should happen when the selection is _changed_, not when the form is _submitted_.

Comment: Updated the logic.

Answer (score 0):

This should work.  When using `type="date"` you need to provide a date in this format `YYYY-MM-DD` ([rfc3339](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc3339)).

**HTML**

```
<html>
<body>

<select onchange="changeDate()">
    <option value="Offered">Tesla</option>
    <option value="Accepted">Volvo</option>
    <option value="Rejected">Mercedes</option>
</select">

  <input type="date" id="date" name="date">
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">


</body>
</html>
```

**Javascript**

```
const changeDate = (val) => {
  
  // Format date to your need
  const now = new Date();
  const day = ("0" + now.getDate()).slice(-2);
  const month = ("0" + (now.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2);
  const today = `${now.getFullYear()}-${month}-${day}`;
  
  console.log(`Today is: ${today}`);
  
  // Set date input
  let date = document.getElementById('date');
  date.value = today;
}
```