# set input of type date value from a string

Tags: javascript, html

I have an API that returns the dates in a string format as shown below. How to set the value of the input type date to this value?

```js
let str = "2020-1-1"
```

```html
<input type= "date" value = {value} />
```

Comment: [`value={str.split('/').reverse().join('-')}`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/date#value)?

Comment: @YevgenGorbunkov it didn't work

Comment: @YevgenGorbunkov not a great solution as it will not take locale's into consideration. Would be best to convert into a javascript `Date()` object first, then set the value. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28729634/set-values-in-input-type-date-and-time-in-javascript/28730034

Comment: @Polymer : *> ...Would be best to...* [No. It wouldn't.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/Date#parameters) (Mind note section). *> ..it will not take locale's into consideration..* and it shouldn't, because, you get this string format from API.

Comment: @nour : of course, it didn't **when you changed input date format**

Comment: @YevgenGorbunkov fair call on the `string` to `Date` conversion, however I stand by the locale point. For all we know the input date could be '1 Jan 2020' at some point. In which case, a library like Luxon or moment.js could help.

Comment: @Polymer : if you get API response format changed, it is normally expected, that you may need to adjust code, consuming that API response. Either way, `'1 Jan 2020'` wouldn't be sufficient reason for me to add 70kB to my bundle, even some ***poor*** choice, like `new Date('1 Jan 2020').toLocaleDateString('en-US').split('/').map(el => el.padStart(2, '0')).reverse().join('-')` seems to be a better option (and proper one wouldn't be much bigger).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will have to format the date into `YYYY-MM-DD` before passing it to the date input.

To do this, you can use:

```js
const str = "29/11/2020";

const [day, month, year] = str.split('/');

const date = `${year}-${month}-${day}`;
```

```html
<input type="date" value={date} />
```

Answer (score 0):

To provide a value to the input field of type `date` you pass value in this format `yyyy-mm-dd`  so regarding you question you should update your date value like this `2021-11-29`

Answer (score 0):

```js
let str = "29/11/2021";
let dateEl = document.getElementById("date");
let value = str.split('/').reverse().join('-');

dateEl.value = value;
```

```html
<input id="date" type= "date" />
```

Comment: can you please show me a way without let dateEl = document.getElementById("date"); because I am using react, I updated my snippet and as u can see it didn't work

Answer (score 0):

That will one possible solution:

```js
const str = "29/11/2020";
const [day, month, year] = str.split('/');
document.getElementById('date').value = `${year}-${month}-${day}`
```

```html
<input id="date" type= "date" />
```

Answer (score 0):

if you use simple **HTML and JavaScript** than provide `id` attribute to input element and assign value on time when you receive data from api

```
<input id='some_unique_id' type= "date" />
```

and on Javascript side use document methods to get element and set value of element

```
const element = document.getElementById('some_unique_id');
element.value = 'your date value'
```

and if you are using **React** with functions components than use `useState` hook

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'

const [value, setValue] = useState(null);
```

and for html side

```
<input value={value} />
```

you can call

> setValue('any value you want')

to set value from where you get api response.

or if you use `classes` in **React** bcz hooks only work in functional components.

```
class Example extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
   super(props);
   this.state = {
     dateValue: new Date()
   };
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <input value={this.state.dateValue} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

you can update state from where you call api and get data like

> this.setState({
> dateValue: 'your api date value'
> })