# How to add number of days to todays date ?(.ics file generator)

Tags: javascript, date, time

I'm looking for the simplest way to add dynamic dates to my events.

```
(function() {
  document.querySelector("#startDate").valueAsDate = new Date();
  document.querySelector("#endDate").valueAsDate = new Date();
  document.querySelector("#endDate").min = new Date()
    .toISOString()
    .substr(0, 10);
```

I was expecting, to be able to add dates simply, but i cant think of a way to do it.

Comment: For adding days to a Date, check out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/563406/how-to-add-days-to-date?rq=1

Comment: For converting dates to yyyy-mm-dd format check out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23593052/format-javascript-date-as-yyyy-mm-dd

Comment: your way of initializing an input date is wrong, because it does not take into account the time difference, which can distort the  date's value. see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28729634/set-values-in-input-type-date-and-time-in-javascript/58252034#58252034

Answer (score 0):

You can add days to any `Date` object by using `.getDate()` and `.setDate()`:

```js
const today=new Date(), in10days=new Date();
in10days.setDate(in10days.getDate()+10);

console.log("today:",today.toISOString())
console.log("in 10 days:",in10days.toISOString());
```